# Is there a way to edit ISO file without changing serial number

Tags: edit, iso, serial-number

I try to build an ISO file and add a software I am making to it. I want to be able to add some files later but not to change the serial number of CD. I tried burning the ISO and I get same serial number 2 times in a row, but the moment I change or add files to that ISO serial number changes.

So my question actually is: is there some method to keep the serial number same but add data to ISO file?

I am using MagicISO to build my ISO file, but I am willing to try everything.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w407S.png)

So I found that actually in MagicISO there is a function to keep the serial number, that for some reason I haven't seen till now. 
It is so simple when you look at it. So you just click **File** -> **Properties** (on the iso image you are using) and in the ISO tab you can choose to keep the serial number or add a new one